# Using custom icons with bootstrap-vue <b-icon>, or a different approach?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a dynamic icon component that gets its icon from a string in the data which I'm using like this:

`<b-icon :icon="my-icon"></b-icon>`

That works well as long as the `my-icon` string in my data matches something available in the [Bootstrap icons list](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/icons). But sometimes `my-icon` is a completely custom string for which I need to create a custom SVG.

Is there an option to provide custom icons for use with an `:icon` prop in `<b-icon>`?
Or should I avoid `<b-icon>` in that particular case and just use another method that would dynamically pull my custom icons *as well as* Bootstrap icons?

Something like this in Vue?

```
<svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
  <use :xlink:href="'bootstrap-icons.svg#' + myIcon" />
</svg>
```

I suppose I'd have to build my own bootstrap-icons.svg file - maybe I could figure that out [from their docs](https://github.com/twbs/icons#adding-svgs).

Essentially...

**How do you approach using icon packs *and* your own custom icons while passing icon name as a prop to a component in Vue?**

Comment: Pleae upvote: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5364

Comment: Take a look of my implementation with Hiws' help on discord: https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/master/spa/src/components/molecules/ShareLink.vue

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there's no way to expose custom SVGs to `<b-icon>`.

You could instead build a wrapper component which that wraps `<b-icon>`, and incorporate your own icons/SVGs into.
First checking if the passed in icon matches any of your own, and if not then fall back to `<b-icon>`.

Alternatively you could take a look at how Bootstrap-Vue [creates their icons](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/tree/dev/src/icons) on the GitHub repo, and copy this method to create your own custom component.